# Is there a way to check against all special characters?

Tags: python, methods

Is there any way to test for all special characters in python other than manually putting them in, perhaps something similar to the .isalnum or .isalpha functions? I'm relatively new to coding, so I have no idea.

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Comment: What sort of special characters are you talking about? The characters one might consider 'special' is dependent on what you're doing.

Comment: `import string` then `help(string)` and read. There are things like `string.punctuation` that might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that any non alphanumeric character counts as special, you can add `not` in front `isalnum` and will return true when there's any special character:

```
test = "1$%a"
print not test.isalnum()
# returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own `is_alphanumeric` function:

```
from string import digits, letters

def is_alphanumeric(mystring):
    """ Returns true if all characters of `mystring` are either letters or digits:
    >>> is_alphanumeric('hello wörld')
    True
    >>> is alphanumeric('Hello World!')
    False
    """
    return all(character in chain(digits, letters) for character in mystring)
```

If you want to restrict it to ascii:

```
from string import digits, letters_ascii

def is_alphanumeric_ascii(mystring):
    """ Returns true if all characters of `mystring` are either ascii    letters or digits: 
    >>> is_alphanumeric('hello wörld')
    False
    >>> is alphanumeric('Hello World')
    True
    """
    return all(character in chain(digits, letters_ascii) for character in mystring)
```